# SQL Server 2012: Mother/Child PK and FK. Unknown Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a question I received:

I have 2 tables.  One is table mother.  The other is child.  They are related to each other because every child has a mother.  I want to relate them directly to each other with a foreign key so that I can't insert a child into the child table unless the child's mother is already in the mother table.  Without knowing the columns, can you write the T-SQL statement that will create a foreign key on the child table to relate it to the mother table?

I'm lost because I thought you had to know the names of the columns in order to assign PK or FK constraints? (I'm an intro to DB student).

Comment: You can do half of this - if you know the name of the column in the child table, and the parent table only has one primary key / unique key, you can just say `REFERENCES dbo.tablename` without a column reference. But this is a terrible idea IMHO. Who gave you a question like this? Do you promise to come back and update us with the reason they want to do something like this *without knowing the columns*? Seriously, ask them that explicitly, "why must this be done without knowing the columns?"

Comment: lol. It's an online class quiz question. She said we could use the internet so I posted it here.
Unfortunately what you see above is all I got. I copied and pasted the question. I will definitely be asking about this question (especially if it's marked wrong) and will update this if I get a response.

Comment: My guess it is possible. It's late so I'm not going to write the T-SQL now, but if you KNOW there is a relationship and you know which one is mother and child, all you would have to do is look for columns with matching data. And then you could create your PK FK relationship. Just check in the child table for columns that only have unique values not null because of them will be the primary. Then simply compare those possible PK columns to data values in the mother table. Once there's a match, it's simple to create the PK FK relationship.

Comment: I received credit for the following answer. Thanks for all your input!!
I do not believe it is possible to create a foreign key without knowing any of the column names on two, already created tables. However, I would probably expand both tables to determine what columns were available. Then I would create the foreign key relationship based on the appropriate columns. I've provided a sample T-SQL statement that could be used:
ALTER TABLE [Child Table]
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK_ID)
REFERENCES [Mother Table](PK_ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to know the names of the columns.  The primary-key-foreign-key relationship you're describing is extremely common, and it's done at database design time.  I'm guessing you're misunderstanding the question because of a comma or clause that was ambiguous.  Or, if it's possible to do it without knowing the column names, it's a weird task that I've never heard of and wouldn't know the reason for.

Comment: Right, I understand the whole "mother/child" relationship. I'm just not sure if it's even possible to create a foreign key without knowing the columns in either table.

Comment: Ok Thanks! I would upvote you but I don't have enough "reputation" lol

Comment: Welcome to SO!  :) You don't have to have reputation to accept an answer to your own question (click the green checkmark under the voting buttons).  But you should accept the answer if it solves your problem, and my answer didn't solve it, unless you've decided it was a trick question.  Maybe there IS a way and I've never heard of it (I seriously doubt it though...)

Comment: Ok, I'll wait and see if it get's marked wrong. I'll update the comments to show my professor's answer.

Comment: I got credit for the following answer: I do not believe it is possible to create a foreign key without knowing any of the column names on two, already created tables. However, I would probably expand both tables to determine what columns were available. Then I would create the foreign key relationship based on the appropriate columns. I've provided a sample T-SQL statement that could be used:
ALTER TABLE [Child Table]
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK_ID)
REFERENCES [Mother Table](PK_ID)